# How To Keep session When close browser laravel

Tags: laravel

i'm done set expire_on_close set off on config/session.php
still not working, session still expired.

```
'lifetime' => 120,

'expire_on_close' => false,
```

Comment: What is your session driver? Did you clear the cache after changing the config?

Answer (score -1):

Sessions are not stored on the server, so you can not save them.
Browser sessions end when the client closes.